# I need help on SQL Queries

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, subquery, where-clause

I need to know if my query is correct or not
this is the database schema:

```
Hotel (hotelNo, hotelName, city)
Room (roomNo, hotelNo, type, price)
Booking (hotelNo, guestNo, dateFrom, dateTo, roomNo)
Guest (guestNo, guestName, guestAddress)
```

List the rooms details that are unoccupied at the hotel number 'H004' in October.
This is what I wrote:

```
 SELECT*
FROM Room r,Hotel h 
WHERE r.hotelNo=h.hotelNo AND hotelNo='H004'
      AND roomNo NOT IN 
      (SELECT roomNo
       FROM Booking b,Hotel h
       WHERE dateFrom='1-Oct'
              AND dateTo='31-Oct'
       AND b.hotelNo=h.hotelNo
        AND hotelNo='H004');
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What are the errors or invalid results that you are getting? Maybe you could break this question into several questions, as it appears to ask multiple unrelated questions. The title could be clearer as well, referring to the error or difficulty you are having. The personal context only adds noise to the question (seriously need help, don't judge me) Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would phrase this with `not exists`:

```
select r.*
from rooms r
where r.hotelno = 'H004' and not exists (
    select 1
    from booking b
    where 
        b.hotelno = r.hotelno 
        and b.roomno = r.roomno
        and b.datefrom <  '2020-11-01'
        and b.dateto   >= '2020-10-01'
)
```

This reads as: find all rooms at the given hotel for which there is no booking that overlaps the month of October 2020.

Notes:

- you don't need to bring the `hotel` table to get the results you want; and if you ever needed to: use standard joins! Implicit joins (with commas in the `from` clause are legacy syntax, that should not be used in new code)
- MySQL understands date literals as strings in format `YYYY-MM-DD`